# void (*(*f[])())() defines f as an array of unspecified size ... what does this means?

Tags: c

`void (*(*f[])())()` defines `f` as an array of unspecified size, of pointers to functions that return pointers to functions that return `void`.

What does this means in a very very very simple explanation

Comment: In very very very simple terms, it means you need to find a different, simpler, way to express whatever this is.

Comment: You can't simplify that explanation without making it wrong.

Comment: I need to understand it , my mind go in a loop every time thinking of it ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine you have a function - let's call it `a()` - that returns void.

`a()` has an address in memory.

Now imagine you have a function `pa()` that returns a pointer to `a()`, i.e. `pa()` returns the address of `a()`.

Now, you don't have just one pair of functions like this but several:

- `b()` returns void, `pb()` returns the address of `b()`
- `c()` returns void, `pc()` returns the address of `c()`

and so on.

Now you want to store the addresses of `pa()`, `pb()`, `pc()` etc in an array, but you don't know how many of them there are yet, so you declare an array of unspecified size to hold all those.

The type of that array, is an array of pointers to functions that return pointers to functions that return void.

Answer (score 3):

If in doubt, typedef:

```
typedef void (*f1)();  // pointer to function returning void
typedef f1 (*f2)();    // pointer to function returning f1

f2 f[];                // your array (not valid C!)
```

The final definition is not valid, because `f[]` is an incomplete type, and you are only allowed to define objects of complete type. A declaration that's not a definition would be OK (`extern f2 f[];`), or you could have a complete type by implying the array size from an braced initializer list, as in `f2 f[] = { a, b, c };`, in which case `f` has (complete) type `f2[3]`.

Note that the above typedef code contains the same number of opening parentheses, closing parentheses, brackets and asterisks as your declaration.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I wish I could undo all my comments from those days. I didn't know any C or C++ then :-(

Comment: @sarnold: I updated the post to include the discussion of why the code is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is *simple*, but `cdecl(1)` can pull it apart for you:

cdecl> explain void (*(*f[])())();
declare f as array of pointer to function returning pointer to function returning void

(Not using the code formatting because it introduces the hateful horizontal scrollbar with that long descriptive line.)